# get strings between 2 delimiter in python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get, from the following string "/path/to/%directory_1%/%directory_2%.csv"

the following list: [directory_1, directory_2]. I would like to avoid using split by "%" my string. I was hoping to find a regex that could help me. However I cannot find the correct one.

For now, I have the following:

```
re.findall('%(.*)%', dirty_arg)
```

which output ["directory_1%/%directory_2"]

Do you have any recommandation about that?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `re.findall(r'%(.*?)%', dirty_arg)` or `re.findall(r'%([^%]*)%', dirty_arg)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

regex = r"%(.*?)%"
dirty_arg = "/path/to/%directory_1%/%directory_2%.csv"

print(re.findall(regex, dirty_arg))
```

---

I've added `?` to your regex which makes sure it matches as few times as possible. The output of this code is `['directory_1', 'directory_2']`

Comment: Please refrain from answering extremely common duplicates. Lazy quantifiers are commonplace, and there are tons of identical questions already posted, explained and demoed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!